# Django : how to translate model the good way

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin, django-i18n

I am trying to translate my model, but it dosen't seem to work.

First, I have tried to translate the model using `ugettext` and `ugettext_laxy`, and by the `Meta` class.

Then, I translated all fields.

I have run the command `python manage.py makemessages -l fr` (returns `processing locale fr`), then `python manage.py compilemessages -l fr`
 (return `processing file django.po in Django\locale\fr\LC_MESSAGES`).

And when I start all:

[image]

*The model are not translated!*

[image: And the field are not translated!]

*And the field are not translated!*

I don't know what I am doing wrong.

**Note:** 1. `LANGUAGE_CODE` is set to `fr`.
          2. `USE_I18N`is set to `True`.

Thanks!

The files : https://gist.github.com/FelixINX/9912fe88a0deb9e3e78181f4f28c0c67

Comment: Have you added the translations **before** running `compilemessages`? The `django.po` file is the output of `makemessages`, not `compilemessages`.

Comment: @schwobaseggl Yes. `compilemessages` output `django.mo`

Comment: have you tried adding the {% load i18n %} tag???

Comment: @0n10n_ is it enable by default? in admin

Comment: no you add it manually between the <!DOCTYPE> and the <html> tags

Comment: @0n10n_ this is not working )-:

Answer (score 0):

Because `Django Admin` page does not have a language switcher you must set your preferred language through your browser settings. In Chrome hit `chrome://settings/languages` and select as first your preferred language. In Firefox hit `about:preferences#content` and edit the `Languages` setting.

Now, concerning the translation of the model fields themselves, you must use the perfect package called [`django-modeltranslation`](https://github.com/deschler/django-modeltranslation).